# How to set reversible animation between state transitions in The Declarative State Machine Framework

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, state-machine, qt3d

I want to use State Machine for an Entity object in Qt3D and make transition animation between its states.

I know about two State Machine frameworks in QML:

1. [Qt Quick States](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-states.html)
2. [The Declarative State Machine Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlstatemachine.html)

First framework is built into QQuickItem that is the base class for all visual items in QtQuick. So these elements have state machine's properties like states, transitions, and so on. Since Entity not inherits QQuickItem, I can only use second framework.

I want my Entity to have 2 states: visible and hidden. When it has state "hidden", Entity would be scaled down to 0. And if it visible, it would be scaled up to 1.
That is my current implementation of Entity states with The Declarative State Machine Framework:

```
import Qt3D 2.0
import Qt3D.Renderer 2.0
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

Entity {
    id: root

    property bool show: true

    components: [
        Transform {
            id: transform
            Scale { id: scale; scale: 1 }
            Translate { ... }
        }
        Mesh { ... },
        Material { ... },

    ]

    DSM.StateMachine {
        id: stateMachine
        initialState: visible
        running: true

        DSM.State {
            id: visible
            DSM.SignalTransition {
                targetState: hidden
                signal: showChanged
                guard: show == false
            }
            onEntered: scale.scale: 1
        }

        DSM.State {
            id: hidden
            DSM.SignalTransition {
                targetState: visible
                signal: showChanged
                guard: show == true
            }
            onEntered: scale.scale: 0
        }
    }
}
```

It works but I want to add animation between transitions. With Qt Quick States I could have use Transition element like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5 as QQ2

Entity {
    ...
    transitions: QQ2.Transition {
            id: tr
            from: "visible"; to: "hidden"; reversible: true
            QQ2.NumberAnimation {
                target: scale
                property: "scale"
                duration: 500
                from: 1; to: 0
            }
        }
}
```

But I can't use it because neither Entity nor DSM.StateMachine nor other parts of DSM framework contain `transitions` property.

I only see quick and dirty solution - add NumberAnimation elements to onEntered slot for every state:

```
    DSM.State {
        id: visible
        onEntered: QQ2.NumberAnimation {
            target: scale; property: "scale"
            to: 1; duration: 1000
        }
    }

    DSM.State {
        id: hidden
        onEntered: QQ2.NumberAnimation {
            target: scale; property: "scale"
            to: 0; duration: 1000
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to use Transition or some other element which has `reversible` property or some way to make reversible animation without redeclaring reverse animation for every state?

Comment: You could also bind the `scale` property to the `visible` property (`visible ? 1000 : 0`) and then install a `Behavior on scale { NumberAnimation {}} `...

Comment: Thanks for showing me `Behavior` element! I see It is a short and pretty way to build some property change animations. But for more complicated task I'd like to use state machine and transitions.